# What is this"�" and how to remove this

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a html websie with some javascript and css .I Just wondered to see this icon "�" in my page .
Please Help me to remove this and If possible tell me what is This

Comment: it's a character that isn't printable, but isn't "white space" -hth

Comment: There's a conflict between the character encoding your server uses and the saved file.

Answer (score 2):

This is a character that your Website isn't able to Print.
There are two things you could try to fix this.

1. Add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your head tag
2. Check your editor setting and make sure its UTF-8